# Stealing my property back?

Tags: canada

So my sister has a few of my clothes and some personal items that she borrowed from me . She claims I gave her the personal items and I never gave her any of it . I’ve asked multiple times for it back . Would it be illegal if I go to her house and take my stuff back ?? She has harassed and threatened me about me wanting my stuff back even said she’s gonna hit me when I’m not pregnant. Could I charge her with harassment and conversion?

Comment: Hello Makayla!  Welcome to Law.SE.  Please read our [tour page](https://law.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be illegal if I go to her house and take my stuff back?

**Yes.**

There is a dispute about who owns the property - you say its yours and she says its hers. One of you is wrong. If its you, then taking it would be a crime.

You could take her to court and prove that you own the items and get an order for their return. Be aware that she might be right and, if so, you will lose.

Comment: Do you want to add information regarding entering his sister's house, presumably without her permission, even if the items' ownership was undisputed?

Comment: That would be very, very risky, since the sister, upset about losing the items, might start disputing the ownership now for the first time, and then we are back with part 1 of Dale’s answer and the person possibly in jail.